# Neo4j.rb query in and out separately for both relationship

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, neo4j, neo4j.rb

Here is my Neo4j Model

```
class User
 include Neo4j::ActiveNode
 has_many :both, :followers, type: :following, model_class: 'User'
end
```

**user1 has 2 out and 1 in like following**

> user1 ---> user2
>
> user1 ---> user3
>
> user1 <--- user3

If I query like following it returns both in/out

```
user1.followers.count #returns 3
```

I want to separately query **in** and **out** for a **User**

How can i do this with Neo4j.rb..

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since the association dictates how match Cypher is written, you can't override the method when called to change its behavior. The solution is to create two more associations.

```
class User
  include Neo4j::ActiveNode
  has_many :both, :followers, type: :following, model_class: 'User'
  has_many :out,  :following, type: :following, model_class: 'User'
  has_many :in,   :followed_by, type: :following, model_class: 'User'
  end
end

# Or, to make it feel more Ruby...

class User
  include Neo4j::ActiveNode
  [[:both, :followers], [:out, :following], [:in, :followed_by]].each do |dir, assoc|
    has_many dir, assoc, type: :following, model_class: 'User'
  end
end


2.2.0 :008 >   User.followers.to_cypher
 => "MATCH (node2:`User`), (result_followers:`User`), node2-[rel1:`following`]-(result_followers:`User`)" 
2.2.0 :009 > User.following.to_cypher
 => "MATCH (node2:`User`), (result_following:`User`), node2-[rel1:`following`]->(result_following:`User`)" 
2.2.0 :010 > User.followed_by.to_cypher
 => "MATCH (node2:`User`), (result_followed_by:`User`), node2<-[rel1:`following`]-(result_followed_by:`User`)"
```

Comment: I was was just writing a similar statement although yours is far more explanatory.

Comment: I figured as much when I saw that upvote come in within seconds of posting! :-)

Comment: @subvertallchris great answer.. +1 for using to_cypher method